# pass parameters via http post method

Tags: java, http-post

I have two text boxes, 1 for username and the other for password.
I wanted to pass what the user enters into the edit texts with the post method

```
String request = "https://beta135.hamarisuraksha.com/web/webservice/HamariSurakshaMobile.asmx/getIMSafeAccountInfoOnLogon";
                URL url;

                try {
                    url = new URL(request);
                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                            .openConnection();
                    connection.setDoOutput(true);
                    connection.setDoInput(true);
                    connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
                    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;");// boundary="+CommonFunctions.boundary
                    connection.setUseCaches(false);

                    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                            connection.getOutputStream());
                    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
                    wr.flush();
                    wr.close();


                    int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                    /*
                     * System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " +
                     * url); System.out.println("Post parameters : " +
                     * urlParameters);
                     */
                    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

                    InputStream errorstream = connection.getErrorStream();

                    BufferedReader br = null;
                    if (errorstream == null) {
                        InputStream inputstream = connection.getInputStream();
                        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputstream));
                    } else {
                        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(errorstream));
                    }
                    String response = "";
                    String nachricht;
                    while ((nachricht = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        response += nachricht;
                    }

                    // print result
                    // System.out.println(response.toString());
                    return response.toString();

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i am getting your question correctly , you need to pass your parameters to a web service. in my case i have implemented a method to get the web service response by giving the url and the values as parameters. i think this will help you.

```
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(JSONObject parm,String url) throws JSONException {


         InputStream is = null;
         JSONObject jObj = null;
         String json = "";
        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            /*JSONObject parm = new JSONObject();
            parm.put("agencyId", 27);
            parm.put("caregiverPersonId", 47);*/

        /*  if(!(jObj.isNull("d"))){
                jObj=null;
            }
            */


            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            HttpEntity body = new StringEntity(parm.toString(), "utf8");
            httpPost.setEntity(body);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            is = httpEntity.getContent();          

               /* String response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                Log.w("myApp", response);*/

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

     //   JSONObject jObj2 = new JSONObject(json);
        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
             jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
```

this method take two parameters. one is the url, other one is the values that we should send to the web service. and simply returns the json object.  hope this will help you

EDIT

to pass your username and password just use below code

```
    JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();  // create instance for the jsonparse class

    String caregiverID = MainActivity.confirm.toString();

    JSONObject param = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject job =  new JSONObject();
    try {
        param.put("username", yourUserNAme);
        job = jp.getJSONFromUrl(param, yourURL);
```

Comment: srry sir i did not understood any thing:(

Comment: you need to send the username and the password to your web service and get the response right ?

Comment: ya but i havnt used json and also the username and password will come from the textbox

Comment: it is really easy..just read about it.in your code you only need to pass your web service url and the username and the password for the param parameter.

Comment: it would b very gratefull if you can show me 
i m confused